# How can I open Windows Disk Defragmenter

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, defragmentation

How can I open Windows Disk Defragmenter using vb.net?

I have tried all the "Google" solutions but none seem to work.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Process.Start("dfrgui.exe")

    End Sub
```

and...

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim sysFolderPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System)
        Process.Start(sysFolderPath + "\dfrgui.exe")

    End Sub
```

and...

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Shell("dfrgui.exe")

    End Sub
```

Comment: What do you get as error or something?

Comment: No, no errors just doesn't execute dfrgui.exe program

Comment: I would assume you are testing this on a windows server machine. Do you have any windows logs

Comment: Try opening your program with administrator rights?

Comment: Process.Start("dfrgui.exe") Seems to work for most things, just not dfrgui.exe. So it is something with the application, as mentioned you may need to call it as an admin.

Comment: Event viewer reads "The Disk Defragmenter service entered the running state" but the GUI does not appear nor does the process show in task manager.

Comment: I am the only user on my comp and have full admin rights.

Comment: Note, on Windows 7 up being an Admin may not be the same as running as Admin. Windows 8 never is, unless you have clicked through the secure shell already. Its a good thing too, but an odd thing for old school Windows users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you compile your code for x86 target systems. Try x64 as target.

Comment: It is set to "Any CPU", but opened config manager and set as x64 which did the trick thanks! I thought as it was set to "Any CPU" it would auto detect but obviously not.

Answer (score 0):

System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\pathhere")

Comment: `System.Diagnostics` is not needed as using VS2013 and is auto added (I think) but have tried `Imports System.Diagnostics` also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim Pwd As Security.SecureString

Pwd = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "Your Passwork").SecurePassword

Process.Start("dfrgui.exe", userName:="Your UserName", password:=Pwd, domain:="Your Computer Domain or Workgroup")
```